# Count rows that have cell don't existing in a list in Excel

Tags: excel-2007, worksheet-function

Please see my image

[image]

I am have two questions:

1. Do you know what is the proper function to count number of rows that have F column value don't exist in range J3:J15 (expect result is 3, as the image)
2. List/or show values in Column A, B of above rows (the rows that have F column value don't existing)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Way №1**

In cell `H2` use:

```
=IF(ISNUMBER(MATCH(F2,$J$3:$J$15,0));"exist in list","not exist in list")
```

and drag it down.

Then in `C12` you can use:

```
=COUNTIF(H2:H8;"not exist in list")
```

### [image]

**Way №2**

In `C12` use:

```
=SUMPRODUCT(1*NOT(ISNUMBER(MATCH($F$2:$F$8,$J$3:$J$15,0))))
```

This is an *array formula*, so type the formula then press <kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>SHIFT</kbd>+<kbd>ENTER</kbd>. Curly brackets will automatically appear at the start and end of the formula.

Then for returning list of corresponding values in column `A` use, say, in `F12`:

```
=IFERROR(INDEX(A:A,SMALL(IF(NOT(ISNUMBER(MATCH($F$2:$F$8,$J$3:$J$15,0))),ROW($F$2:$F$8)),ROW()-ROW($F$12)+1)),"")
```

this is also array formula, so press <kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>SHIFT</kbd>+<kbd>ENTER</kbd> to evaluate it and then drag formula down.

and in `G12` for returning corresponding values from column `B`:

```
=IFERROR(INDEX(B:B,SMALL(IF(NOT(ISNUMBER(MATCH($F$2:$F$8,$J$3:$J$15,0))),ROW($F$2:$F$8)),ROW()-ROW($F$12)+1)),"")
```

also with array entry(<kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>SHIFT</kbd>+<kbd>ENTER</kbd>).

[image]

Comment: Thanks @Simoco very much, could you see more simple image: [link](https://www.mediafire.com/?w1azh3832ti8xmc). How to list values of column B, that have value of G is "ONT" (same row) as my image.

Comment: use this one in, say, `E31` : `=IFERROR(INDEX(B:B,SMALL(IF($G$21:$G$27="ONT",ROW($G$21:$G$27)),ROW()-ROW($E$31)+1)),"")`, press CTRL+SHIFT+ENTER to evaluate it and drag formula down

Comment: Hi @simoco, I got an error with your formular. You used: IF($G$21:$G$27="ONT",ROW($G$21:$G$27)). Is this correct?

Comment: yes, it is correct, have you pressed CTRL+SHIFT+ENTER to evaluate the formula?

Comment: see formulas in cells `D31` and `D32` in this test workbook: https://www.dropbox.com/s/yl3sd1nwyr3b40n/Book2.xlsx

Comment: Thanks @simoco. That is ok now, but if I want to add one more condition: value of column D >= 200. How can change the formula ?

Comment: just change `$G$21:$G$27="ONT"` to `($G$21:$G$27="ONT")*($D$21:$D$27>=220)`

Comment: Thanks simoco very much